# Java7 multiple exception handling

Tags: java, exception, java-7

I have been trying to find out answer to this question but did not get any satisfactory explanation. Here is some background:

Java 7 allows us to catch multiple exceptions in a single catch block provided those exceptions are from diffrent hierarchy. Eg:

```
try {
    // some code

} catch(SQLException | FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But if exceptions are from the same hierarchy we must use multiple catch blocks like:

```
try {
    // some code
} catch(FileNotFoundException  e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But if I try to write code like below compiler complains that "The exception `FileNotFoundException` is already caught by the alternative `IOException`"

```
try {
    // some code
} catch(FileNotFoundException | IOException  e) { // compiler error
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now my question is: Why compiler reports an error in last case, can't it figure out that `FileNotFoundException` is special case of `IOException`? This would save code duplication when my exception handling logic is same.

Comment: If you are handling `IOException`, then no need to use same handler block for   `FileNotFoundException`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why compiler reports an error in last case, can't it figure out that `FileNotFoundException` is special case of `IOException`?

Because `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`. In other words, the "`FileNotFoundException |`" part is redundant.

The reason why the code below is ok...

```
} catch(FileNotFoundException  e) {
    ...
} catch(IOException e) {
    ...
}
```

...is because here the `IOException` clause matters: If a `SocketException` is thrown for instance, it will pass the by the `FileNotFoundException` part, and get caught in the `IOException` clause.

Answer (score 0):

When catching an exception you have order your catch clauses from the most specific to the most general.

Consider the following hierachy:

```
class MyException extends Exception {}

class MySubException extends MyException  {}
```

If a part of your code throws MyException an an other part throws MySubException you have to catch MySubException first.

```
catch(MySubException e){

} catch(MyException e){

}
```

Its the same thing like using the instanceof operator.

If you test if an instance of MySubException is an instanceof MyException the result will be true.

```
mse = new MySubException();

if(mse instanceof MyException){
    println("MyException");
} else if(mse instanceof MySubException){
    println("MySubException");
}
```

This piece of code will never print "MySubException".

```
mse = new MySubException();

if(mse instanceof MySubException){
    println("MySubException");
} else if(mse instanceof MyException){
    println("MyException");
}
```

This would be the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Its because FileNotFoundException extends IOException, as you said its of same hierarchy, you cannot add them to same catch block.